# Fastest way to iterate pixels in a canvas and copy some of them in another one

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, putimagedata

I'm into a 2D/3D graphic project and I'm facing a performance problem.

My algorithm takes two images: a picture and the relative grayscale depth map.
I have also an array of 10 canvases ("layers") initally blank. A note: all the images have the same dimension.

I need to check every pixel X;Y of the depth map and, depending on its color value, access one of the 10 canvases and draw the X;Y pixel of the original image on it.

Resulting algorithm is someting like:

```
for (var y = 0; y < totalHeight; ++y) {
   for (var x = 0; x < totalWidth; ++x) {
     var index = (y * totalWidth + x) * 4; // index of the current pixel
     // parse depth level using luminosity method
     var depthLevel = Math.round(
         0.21 * depthData[index] + 
         0.71 * depthData[index + 1] + 
         0.07 * depthData[index + 2]
     );

     // get the proper layer to modify
     var layerIndex = Math.floor((layersCount / 256) * depthLevel);
     var layerContext = layers[layerIndex].getContext("2d");
     var layerData = layerContext.getImageData(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);

     layerData.data[index] = originalData[index];
     layerData.data[index + 1] = originalData[index + 1];
     layerData.data[index + 2] = originalData[index + 2];
     layerData.data[index + 3] = originalData[index + 3];

     layerContext.putImageData(layerData, 0, 0);
}
```

A loop like that takes around 3 minutes to complete on a 200x200 image! I'm pretty sure that the slowness is caused by the last function, putImageData. Is there a faster way to draw pixels in the way I need? Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't set your image data in every iteration of the loop. That's a heavy operation, and you're executing it `40.000` <sup>`(200*200)`</sup> times.
This should save you a bit of processing power:

```
var contexts = [];
var data = [];
// Save your contexts and data to 2 arrays.
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    contexts[i] = layers[i].getContext("2d");
    data[i] = contexts[i].getImageData(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);
}

for (var y = 0; y < totalHeight; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < totalWidth; ++x) {
        var index = (y * totalWidth + x) * 4; // index of the current pixel
        // parse depth level using luminosity method
        var depthLevel = Math.round(
            0.21 * depthData[index]
          + 0.71 * depthData[index + 1]
          + 0.07 * depthData[index + 2]);

        // get the proper layer to modify
        var layerIndex = Math.floor((layersCount / 256) * depthLevel);

        data[layerIndex].data[index] = originalData[index];
        data[layerIndex].data[index + 1] = originalData[index + 1];
        data[layerIndex].data[index + 2] = originalData[index + 2];
        data[layerIndex].data[index + 3] = originalData[index + 3];
    }
}

// Apply your new data to the contexts.
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) { 
    contexts[i].putImageData(data[i]);
}
```

I haven't tested it, but this should give you a bit of an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Is there a "Saviour" badge for you? :) thank you so much, now it's fast as light