# Best Practices For Heavy Computations in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, heavy-computation

I am working on client side scripts and need to do heavy computations like pushing huge number of objects in an array, it causes JavaScript to stop response and browser hangs giving an alert:

[image: Browser Warning]

Is there any best practices or design patterns for handling these computation, I search and find many different ways to handle these situation but solutions are difficult to implement so I need best practices and easy to understand?

(I am writing code just for example But I need a general solution that is cross-browser i.e, multi-threading etc)

Example Code (series contains thousands of objects):

```
for (var series = 0; series < chartObj.masterChart.series.length; series++) {
    var detailData = [];
    jQuery.each(chartObj.masterChart.series[series].data, function (i, point) {
        if (point.x >= chartObj.RangeSelectedMinValue && point.x <= chartObj.RangeSelectedMaxValue) {
            detailData.push({
                x: point.x,
                y: point.y
            });
        }
    });
    chartObj.detailChart.series[series].setData(detailData);
}
```

Comment: In my opinion Javascript shouldn't do any heavy computation. Heavy means huge number of data or realy difficult algorithms which take a lot of time.

Comment: Show us some code or tell logic to comment

Comment: That's quite an open topic. Posting some code to make it specific would be a better step.

Comment: Many things are difficult to implement. The solution is not to find easier things but to try harder.

Comment: So, what are you doing to cause that?
We can't help you optimize your code without a clue of what you're doing.

Comment: I agree, javascript should not be use for these computation, but If someone have to use this then what is best to implement? I can write code but want open solution that can be implemented anywhere.

Comment: `setTimeout` with proper continuations every now and again?

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: We can say things like "Avoid **Massive** Loops, Avoid **Huge** arrays / objects, [don't use heavy operations in each iteration of a loop, if it can be done outside of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917139/fastest-way-to-iterate-pixels-in-a-canvas-and-copy-some-of-them-in-another-one), but all of that is **way** to generic for the StackOverflow Q&A format.

Comment: I'd say web workers were created for this purpose. Only works in *real browsers*™ though. http://dev.w3.org/html5/workers/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Worker https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

Comment: Not to degrade your answer or anything, but support for workers [isn't universal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers#Browser_Compatibility), yet.
Depending on the browser used, this can be a **very** (if not "the") good option, though.

Comment: Hence the "real browsers" comment.

Comment: Whoops, missed that, my bad -.-

Comment: +1 Nice!! but need to support IE7 and IE8 too :(

Answer (score 5):

Okay, looking at your code, there's a few things you can optimize:

```
var s = chartObj.masterChart.series, // #1
    sLength = s.length,              // #2
    chartMin = chartObj.RangeSelectedMinValue,
    chartMax = chartObj.RangeSelectedMaxValue;
for (var series = 0; series < sLength; series++) {
    var detailData = [],
        data = s[series].data,       // #3
        length = data.length;        // #2
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){ // #4
        var point = data[i];
        if (point.x >= chartMin && point.x <= chartMax) {
            detailData.push({
                x: point.x,
                y: point.y
            });
        }

    }
    chartObj.detailChart.series[series].setData(detailData);
}
```

1. You're getting the same "deeper" object inside chartObj multiple times --> Assign it to a temporary variable;
2. Don't calculate the length for every iteration of the loop. Same principle as #1
3. Assign `s[series].data` to a temp var. This provides a direct pointer to the data instead of having to access `s[series].data` each iteration of the loop. Same principle as #1
4. jQuery is slow. For a simple loop, use JavaScript instead, **especially** if you're looping through a massive object.

I'm not saying this edit will work miracles, but it should reduce the load a bit.

Comment: Thank you nice optimization, implemented!!! :) but still facing problems that is why I ask a general solution? -- Nice +1

Comment: I think those 4 points are pretty much as "general" as I can make it. Although, I found 1 more edit I could make. (`chartMin /chartMax`)

Answer (score 5):

You should use [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

They are [really supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) 
and they are real threads in javascript as they spawn real OS threads!

## Example

## `main.js`

```
var heavy_process = new Worker('heavy_process.js');

heavy_process.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  // Log the workers message.
  console.log(e.data);
}, false);

heavy_process.postMessage();
```

## heavy_process.js:

```
for (var series = 0; series < chartObj.masterChart.series.length; series++) {

  var detailData = [];
  jQuery.each(chartObj.masterChart.series[series].data, function (i, point) {
      if (point.x >= chartObj.RangeSelectedMinValue && point.x <= chartObj.RangeSelectedMaxValue) {
        detailData.push({
            x: point.x,
            y: point.y
        });
      }
  });
  chartObj.detailChart.series[series].setData(detailData);
  // you should use self.postMessage here !!!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could split it in to different "threads" by using timeouts. Like so:

```
var counter;

function longRun(start) {
    counter = 0;

    for (var i = start; i < 3000; i++) {

        counter++;
        console.log(i);
        if (counter > 99) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                longRun(i+1)
            }, 0);
                console.log('counter at: ' + i + ' start fake "thread"');
            return;
        }
    }
    alert('Done!');
}
longRun(0);​
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MSYvp/33/)

I guess it would prevent the warning, but I don't know how sane it really is.

Comment: I am fully aware that there are no threads per se in JavaScript, hence the quotation marks. But in this specific case the method of splitting the code into chunks makes the program handle 100 iterations at a time works.

I think I made it clear with the quotation marks and the log statement in the code that I am not talking about real threads. It was a word I choose to compare it to another know pattern.

I am Sorry if I was confusing anyone

Comment: Not only does JavaScript not have threads, it has no concept of parallel execution whatsoever. setTimeout or no, it's impossible to have two functions running at the same time - they will always be run in serial. So this solution won't really do anything but slow down your code.

Comment: At no point in my answer did I say that my solution would execute functions in parallel.The point is to exit the currently running function and start again with a new start value. The main point here was to get rid of the browser warning, which my example did.